# Logback overrides dependencies logback.xml

Tags: java, maven, logging, dependencies, logback

I'm developing an application using another of my project as a maven dependency.

**Expectation**

I want my dependency using its own logback.xml to log in its own file.
And I want the application using its own logback.xml file to log in the console and a separate file than the dependency. And I want both files in a log folder near the application jar.

**What it does now**

But for the moment both the application and the dependency use the application's logback.xml and everything is logged in the console and in the same file.

How can I solve this problem?

**Details about the projects**

Both use logback as a logger. The dependency is a protocol implementation that logs communication information in a file that must be in a separate file than application logs.
Both the application and the dependency have a classic maven structure with the logback.xml file inside the resource folder.

**The dependency logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss}|%msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>./log/communications.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

**The application logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="FILEAPPLI" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss}|%msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>./log/debugfileappli.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILEAPPLI"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In my dependency code I call a specific logger name.

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("dependencyLogger");
```

And I declare this logger in my application logback.xml

```
<logger name="dependencyLogger" level="debug">
    <additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

In this way I can handle as I want all the log from the dependency in a single logback.xml